# I get error "Image source not readable" when uploading image in my Laravel app on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel

I get "image source not readable error" when trying to upload image with a Laravel app deployed on heroku. I am using the intervention/image package for handling the image.

Here is the error encountered:
[Image of upload error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8uKk.png)

And here is my code:

```js
$path = $req->cover->store('uploads','public');

//cut image with intervention image library
$image = Image::make(public_path("/storage/{$path}"))->resize(1344,652)->save();
```

Please how can I resolve this issue?